# AngularJS custom filter trigger on select drop down

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS. I have a custom filter like this.

```
app.filter('makeUppercase', function () {
  return function (item) {
    return item.toUpperCase();
  };
});
```

On ng-change I want to trigger my custom filter. Means, when user select option1 I want to trigger the above filter.

```
  <md-select ng-model="myModel" ng-change="" placeholder="Select an option">
```

Comment: I just want to trigger that. @31piy

Comment: @31piy plz help

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {

  $scope.option = ["option01", "option02", "option03"];

  angular.element(document.querySelector('#option')).on('change', function() {    
    var a = this.selectedOptions[0].label;
    console.log(a);
    $scope.result = $filter('makeUppercase')(a);
    console.log($scope.result);
  })

});
app.filter('makeUppercase', function() {
  return function(item) {
    console.log("OK");
    return item.toUpperCase();
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select id="option" ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in option ">
</select>

</div>
```

Comment: This is similar to what I want. I need small help. Can you help me with the ng-change="" ? Instead of using angular.element(document.querySelector('#option') this way, any options?

Comment: I try to do what you want but I couldn't do so that why I code this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to create a select list. So you can do like this.

```
<select ng-model="myModel" ng-options="obj as (obj | makeUppercase) for obj in objects" placeholder="Select an option">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to achieve this question but I would prefer a total Angular solution.Below is a HTML template based on what I understood from your question.

The  moment you select a value from the drop down the ng-model value is turned into UPPERCASE from the filter you created.

**HTML**

```
<div role="main" class="container theme-showcase" ng-app="angularTable">
        <div class="" style="margin-top:90px">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="page-header"></div>
                <div class="bs-component" ng-controller="listdata">
                    <select ng-options="x.username as x.username  for x  in users" ng-model="myModel" ng-change="optionChanged()"></select>
                    {{myModel | makeUppercase }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('angularTable', []);

app.controller('listdata', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.users = [];
    $scope.myModel;

    $http.get("demo.json").success(function(response) {
        $scope.users = response;
        console.log($scope.users);
    });

    $scope.optionChanged = function() {

        console.log("options have been changed..");

    };

});

app.filter('makeUppercase', function() {
    return function(item) {
        if (item) {
            console.log(item)
            return item.toUpperCase();
        }
    };
});
```

Working [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/84JiNSsxMTdDHy1VlJcr?p=preview)

Comment: In ng change you have only done -     $scope.optionChanged = function() {

        console.log("options have been changed..");

    };

Comment: You can do what ever you want in ng-change function, I already applied the filter in HTML itself hence I left the function empty.